# Failing to customize form field label size in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

We are using angular material in our app.
I am trying to find a way to make the floating labels of all fields bigger.

As an examples:
[image]

I can, of course, just drive it by additional class, but:
 * I will have to do it on each and every field
 * In case of an outlined field (as shown), the text will be on top of the border.

How can I make the change globally? and how to make sure that the space for the label text also increased?

Comment: The size relationship between label and field value is achieved using a scale transform `transform: translateY(-1.59375em) scale(.75);` in the class `mat-form-field-label`. The translateY will also need to be changed in order to position the label properly. Already this is a bit complicated. For Outline fields, you will also need to modify the outline border so that the gap matches the size of the label. The outline is actually 3 pieces: `mat-form-field-outline-start`, `mat-form-field-outline-gap`, and `mat-form-field-outline-end`. Now it's really complicated. Not worth the effort IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I handled this by overriding a couple things in a global SCSS/CSS file.

1. Keep the translateY() value and change the scale to be 1.

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label,  
 .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float .mat-input-server:focus + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label { 
        transform: translateY(-1.7175em) scale(1);
    }
```

2. Apply your font changes to the label, and add background to it, which overlaps with the outline and makes it look like there is the desired gap.

```
.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {   
    letter-spacing: 0.025rem;
     line-height: 1.34;
      font: {
        size:  0.75rem;
        weight: 600;
      }
    
          mat-label {
           background: white;

            &::after {
              background: white;
              content: '';
              display: inline-block;
              width: 0.25rem;
            }
          }
```

Comment: You'll need to throw an `!important` at the end of the changed scale value: 

`transform: translateY(-1.7175em) scale(1) !important;` 
Otherwise Material will  overwrite it and keep it at .75

Comment: @SteveWhitmore since I added these to the global styles, I don't need `!important`

Answer (score 0):

They are all dominated by the selector of `.mat-form-field-label` that you can manipulate your self, but it will change all the behaviours of it's translation and scale from label to floating label so it's a little bit complicated if you can not handle modifications of its translation and typography.